# how can i get particular text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i get only the cheque number(`AA12GH56`) not the other texts, here is my code:

HTML:

```
<p>your cheque number is :AA12GH56 <br /> your bank credit balance is :32,999</p>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('p').click(function(){
    var cheque_no=$(this).text();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either a regular expression or a precision `.split` is what you need. I'm a fan of the latter technique -- what it loses in brevity it makes up in clarity.

```
var cheque_no=$(this).text().split(':')[1].split('your')[0];
cheque_no = $.trim(cheque_no); // remove whitespace
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/c6Zms/

Comment: @Chango I agree; I prefer your `span` approach. However, I assumed that OP couldn't modify the source HTML for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

You should use javascript's regular expressions if you can't modify the html. I recomend this page to learn: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml

If you can modify the html I would put the cheque number inside a span with a proper class name (or id):

```
<p>
  your cheque number is <span id="cheque-number">:AA12GH56</span> <br /> 
  your bank credit balance is :32,999
</p>
```

so the javascript would be:

```
$('p').click(function(){  var cheque_no=$(this).find("#cheque-number").text();  });  });
```

Comment: You should modify your code so that he can still click anywhere on the `<p>` and still get just the `cheque-number`.